# Solr DIH-Troubles When Getting Files From Ftp servers In TikaEntity Processor. How Can I pass credentials to UrlDataSource?

Tags: solr, apache-tika, dih

I have some troubles when I tried to get files from a ftp severs to extract some metadata with tikaEntityProcessor.

I need a way to pass some credentials to the UrlDataSource.

Can anyone, please, tell me how can I do that?

Example values:

> **url**:
>   ftp://localhost/Oreilly.Mercurial.The.Definitive.Guide.Jun.2009.pdf
>
> **ftp user**: alex
>
> **ftp password**: pass

This is my `Data-config.xml`

```
<dataConfig>  
    <dataSource type="BinURLDataSource" name="binSource" 
        baseUrl="ftp://localhost:21/" onError="skip" />     
     <dataSource type="JdbcDataSource"
                 driver="org.postgresql.Driver"
                 url="jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/files"
                 user="postgres"
                 password="admin" 
                 readOnly="true" 
                 autoCommit="false"
                 transactionIsolation="TRANSACTION_READ_COMMITTED"
                 holdability="CLOSE_CURSORS_AT_COMMIT"/>
    <document>
        <entity name="item" query="select* from filesfromftp"
                deltaQuery="select url from filesfromftp"
                rootEntity="false"
                transformer="RegexTransformer">            
                <field column="url" name="id" />            
                <entity name="tika-test" 
                        processor="TikaEntityProcessor" 
                        url="${item.url}" 
                        format="none"
                        dataSource="binSource"                          
                        onError="skip">                     
                  <field column="Author" name="author" meta="true"/>
                  <field column="title" name="title" meta="true"/>
                  <field column="pdf:docinfo:title" name="title" meta="true"/>
                  <field column="xmpTPg:NPages" name="numPages" meta="true"/>
                  <field column="Creation-Date" name="createdDate" meta="true"/>
                </entity>
        </entity>
    </document>
</dataConfig>
```

When I execute Data Import Handler I get this error:

```
Exception in entity : tika-test:org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.DataImportHandlerException: Exception in invoking url ftp://localhost/jnioche-bristoljavameetup20150310-150311041443-conversion-gate01.pdf Processing Document # 1
    at org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.DataImportHandlerException.wrapAndThrow(DataImportHandlerException.java:69)
    at org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.BinURLDataSource.getData(BinURLDataSource.java:89)
    at org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.BinURLDataSource.getData(BinURLDataSource.java:38)
    at org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.TikaEntityProcessor.nextRow(TikaEntityProcessor.java:128)
    at org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.EntityProcessorWrapper.nextRow(EntityProcessorWrapper.java:244)
    at org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.DocBuilder.buildDocument(DocBuilder.java:475)
    at org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.DocBuilder.buildDocument(DocBuilder.java:516)
    at org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.DocBuilder.buildDocument(DocBuilder.java:414)
    at org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.DocBuilder.doFullDump(DocBuilder.java:329)
    at org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.DocBuilder.execute(DocBuilder.java:232)
    at org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.DataImporter.doFullImport(DataImporter.java:416)
    at org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.DataImporter.runCmd(DataImporter.java:475)
    at org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.DataImporter.lambda$runAsync$0(DataImporter.java:458)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: sun.net.ftp.FtpLoginException: Invalid username/password
    at sun.net.www.protocol.ftp.FtpURLConnection.connect(FtpURLConnection.java:308)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.ftp.FtpURLConnection.getInputStream(FtpURLConnection.java:393)
    at org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.BinURLDataSource.getData(BinURLDataSource.java:86)
    ... 12 more
```

Please, how can I establish a connection with a FtpServer within SolrDIH?

Is there a way to pass some credentials to UrlDataSource?

Answer (score 0):

There is a patch available [here](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SOLR-1490)for this purpose. It is very old, but you could port it to a newer version. Look at a quite recent comment showing how you can create your custom URLDataSource with auth.